# Can't install module with Python

Tags: python, pip

I try to install a cryptography module on Python, im making :

```
pip install cryptography
```

And if I try to import it :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

I also tried an another command :

```
python -m pip install cryptography
```

And this time I have... :

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: No module named pip
```

Comment: Provide a part of your code. You probably install it to a different version or to a virtual enviroment than this you're trying to import it.

Comment: what is your Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue, it was some path problem :

**Panel config.>System&Security>System>Advanced>Var. Environnement**

And I add : C:\Users\alimacher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts

Now it works...
Thanks All !